# What items provide quick heals in dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I'm quite a beginner in dota 2, have gotten used to the game and I understand some basics of healing,I used to buy a bottle in every game because I always run out of mana/health or both very quickly but refilling it is difficult as I need to be on a constant lookout for runes or sometimes even teleport back to the fountain.

My question is, what items provide some quick or efficient heals without forcing me to go back to the base?

Comment: Most of the time you don't buy a bottle unless you are going mid lane since that provides the best rune access. Also, there is the option of giving the bottle to a courier to refill it back at your fountain so you don't have to leave the lane, although this strategy is not efficient and you don't want to hog the courier from your allies.

Comment: @Kotsu's advice is now a little out of date, for those turning up now. The fact that 2 runes spawn every 2 minutes makes having 2 bottles on a team perfectly reasonable, usually for the offlane carry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is 1 more very important item that Lustin didn't mention, and that is the [magic stick](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Magic_Stick).

Early on in the game, this is a great way to get that small burst of health or mana that can often save you from death or provide the ability to get that crucial early kill.

And as you get more money, you can upgrade it into a magic wand for even greater effectiveness.

If you are constantly running out of life/mana, then there are a few things you can do to improve that situation.

1. Buy a Stout Shield.  This protects you quite a bit from ranged harass and can greatly boost your survivability.
2. Watch your positioning.  Don't attack an enemy hero when you are surrounded by creeps as they'll immediately target you.  Don't hang around in the middle of the creep line either.  Only go in for denies or last hits.
3. Don't spam your skills too much unless you'll either a) get a hero kill b) prevent a hero death or c) keep yourself in the lane longer (do this sparingly).  Mana management is very important early on, don't waste it on creeps.
4. Get some branches.  The boost in mana, health, and damage is quite significant early on in the game, and branches will be required to make that magic wand anyway.

Comment: I know this item is only applicable after beating rosh 3 times, but I suppose "Cheese" also fits in the category of a healing item.

Answer (score 13):

To me, this sounds like you're taking unnecessary creep damage. The only time you should take creep damage is when you're harassing an enemy, and even then you want to make sure you take less damage then they do! Make sure you're not doing that and actually warrant heals because these items are all pricey if you don't actually need them! Here are the items that can heal you in the game, excluding the Bottle that you're already aware of (and is more often picked up for mana restoration than for healing).

[image: Tango]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/f/fd/Tango_icon.png))</sub>   - [Tango](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Tango) is a consumable you buy from the main shop with 125 gold. It gives you 4 charges that can be used on a tree to heal you for 115 hp over 16 seconds.

[image: Healing Slave]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/3/36/Healing_Salve_icon.png))</sub>   - [Healing Slave](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Healing_Salve) can be bought for 115 gold from the main shop. If consumed it will heal you for 400 hp over 10 seconds. If you receive damage during this time the effect will be stopped.

[image: Magic Stick]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/5/59/Magic_Stick_icon.png))</sub>   / [image: Magic Wand]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/7/74/Magic_Wand_icon.png))</sub>   - [Magic Stick](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Magic_Stick) and [Magic Wand](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Magic_Wand) are extremely cost efficient items that gain a charge anytime an enemy casts a spell near you. You can activate the item to restore 15 health and 15 mana per charge. This item is also great for making use of Iron Branches that you should buy at the beginning of almost every game.

[image: Ring of Regen]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/6/6d/Ring_of_Regen_icon.png))</sub>   - [Ring of Regen](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Ring_of_Regen) costs 350 gold and can be bought from the main shop or the side lane shop. It will increase your hp regen by 2.

[image: Ring of Health]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/2/29/Ring_of_Health_icon.png))</sub>   - [Ring of Health](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Ring_of_Health) increases your hp regen by 5. It costs 875 gold and can be bought from the secret shop or the side lane shop.

[image: Urn of Shadows]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/5/58/Urn_of_Shadows_icon.png))</sub>   - [Urn of Shadows](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Urn_of_Shadows) costs 875 to make and has an active that will heal an allied hero for 400 hp. The healing is interrupted if the unit takes hero or tower damage.

[image: Tranquil Boots]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/e/ea/Tranquil_Boots_icon.png))</sub>   - [Tranquil Boots](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Tranquil_Boots) costs 975 to make will give you 12 hp regen while out of combat. The healing is interrupted for 13 seconds if the hero attacks or is attacked.

[image: Mekansm]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/f/f7/Mekansm_icon.png))</sub>   - [Mekansm](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Mekansm) is more expensive at 2306 but is a great item for support heroes to make as it heals all allies in a nearby radius for 250 hp instantly. This makes it a great teamfight item and every team should have one.

Comment: Neither ring should be bought *unless* you are planning to use it in the build of something else, e.g. Force Staff or Mekansm.

Comment: This needs an update, new item prices and effects, at least for Tango and Healing Salve.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated those, along with the links and pictures. If I missed anything please tell me.

Comment: Might want to update this to reflect the new passive behavior of Tranquil Boots.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the new [Faerie Fire](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Faerie_Fire) from 6.86: a consumable that restores 75hp and also grants +2 attack